# How to redirect back to the app from SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, redirect, ios-universal-links, safariservices

I want to redirect back to the app after an event (redirect to a universal link) happens on the `SafarViewController`. The only delegate function suitable is

```
func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, initialLoadDidRedirectTo URL: URL)
```

The issue is that we need to redirect after the page was already loaded, hence, this function is not being called.

Alternatively, we could use `WKWebView`, but we must use `SafariServices` instead